# correct order for Postfix milters

Tags: postfix, dkim, clamav, dmarc, milter

I use the following milters with Postfix:

ClamAV, OpenDKIM, OpenDMARC, Rspamd

This is also the order they are being called via `smtpd_milters`.

What would be the best order for them regarding performance, resources and spam protection?

Comment: I would set them up as follows: 1. OpenDKIM 2.OpenDMARC 3. Rspamd 4. ClamAV . The logic being that the most resource intensive operations should only be performed for messages that have been validated by less resource intensive methods.

Comment: Why do you need anything but 'rmilter'? Rspamd can do DKIM and DMARC checks, rmilter, in turn, can do DKIM sign and clamav checks so you won't need anything else.

Comment: rmilter isn't being developed anymore and I want to avoid being stuck with the same decisions at some point in the future. Also rmilter doesn't work with ClamAV without running ClamAV as the _rmilter user. And I never got it to properly make DKIM signatures or add headers about these checks to received emails.

Comment: @vstakhov don't get me wrong: I would love to use only rmilter. But the prospect of having to make the same decision in the foreseeable future is not good. Also I don't want to use memcached since I already use Redis. And as I said: the lack of an up to date guide and more verbose logging for debugging makes it hard to configure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenDKIM, OpenDMARC, Rspamd, ClamAV

I assume you have OpenDMARC configured to do SPF itself? You'll want to disable SPF/DKIM/DMARC checking in Rspamd then as well.

- you need openDKIM before openDMARC so that the DMARC check can be done based on the Auth-Results: header set by openDKIM.
- You want openDMARC before Rspamd so it can send DMARC reports on all messages, not just on those that made it past Rspamd.
- You want Clam last to avoid AV scanning messages that another method of content filtering might block first.

Comment: But I want Rspamd to check SPF/DKIM/DMARC for rating…

Comment: Or what would I win / loose if I disable these checks in Rspamd?

Comment: You can leave the checks on if you like, but it will likely just re-do the same work that openDKIM and openDMARC already performed.

Comment: but it won't send aggregated reports like DMARC would